# Spring for Android - XML parsing with SimpleXML

Tags: android, spring, xml-parsing

I'm trying to using [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) for Android to parse an XML response. I've successfully implemented [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) in the past to parse JSON responses, but I'm running into problems with XML for some reason.

I downloaded and added the [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) jar to my build path. I don't get any compilation errors, but when I run it, I get problems. Here is my code:

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("text","xml")));
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
String url = "MyURL";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter());
try{
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "response - " + responseEntity.getBody());

}catch(HttpMessageNotReadableException e){
    Log.d(TAG, "message " + e.getMessage());
}
```

The error I get when I run this code is the following:

```
02-11 16:49:28.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5454): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-126
02-11 16:49:28.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5454): org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.lang.String]
02-11 16:49:28.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5454):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:632)
02-11 16:49:28.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5454):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:473)
02-11 16:49:28.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5454):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:438)
02-11 16:49:28.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5454):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:414)
02-11 16:49:28.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5454):     at com.rounded.rrbcataloguelibrary.RRBCatalogueActivity.getCategories(RRBCatalogueActivity.java:337)
02-11 16:49:28.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5454):     at com.rounded.rrbcataloguelibrary.RRBCatalogueActivity$7.run(RRBCatalogueActivity.java:395)
02-11 16:49:28.905: E/AndroidRuntime(5454):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

The error is thrown on this line: `ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);`

Just to test, I used this: `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());` from my message converter and I got the proper response as a string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to set the accept headers as the body of the message. That's probably not what you want...

The ResponseEntity should wrap an object that's XML-serializable (looking at the converter code, seems like it's looking for the @Root annotation). Anyway, with Spring you (generally) don't have to worry about setting the accept/content-type headers directly, since those will be set by the MessageConverters.

Comment: I commented out the line that set the accept headers and it didn't make a difference...I've also tried using a couple of different object types for the response entity with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type needs to be something other than String.  I don't know what the SimpleXml one wants but if you were using JaxB it would be the generated classes